# Openerp 7:Generating csv files for Sales Order uploads

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, odoo

I am a developer using pythong for my company,  For Sales Orders (SOs) uploads, my colleagues who use openerp advise it is a bit cryptic to understand, so I developed a script for them.  I am writing a python script to take data from a Libre Office Calc file and generate a csv file.  I have succfessfully written the script which works but fails to work when I add the tax field.

When I download the exported csv file, I get under the order_line/tax_id/id, i have

```
__export__.account_tax_7_3125
```

I think the last set of digits is a counter, so when I try to use this format to upload the csv file, I get an error, so I get rid of the last set of digits and enter the value -

```
__export__.account_tax_7
```

I still get an error.  How can I successfullyy upload the sales tax for my staff to make their lives easier.  We sometimes get over 100 quotations and entering taxes for each of them may be a problem.  Someone please assist....
I will need a a proper value for this csv field order_line/tax_id/id...
Thanks

Comment: Hi, what is the input from your users for tax field inside CALC file ?

Comment: The inputs from the ods file are the name of the customer (exactly as it is on openERP), the Internal Reference and the quantity, with this I generate all the data I need for teh csv.  I go to the account_tax table and choose the standard Value Added Tax 5.00% which has an id of 7 in my table so I generate the value under tax_id/id -- __export__.account_tax_7.... This is what I do...

Comment: You have write down script for that. So, just use actual database ID (i.e. 7) to set tax inside sale order line. Is it not good ? If you want to set using script then let me know. I will help you to do this.

Comment: Do you mean I should write directly to the database instead of creating a csv??  Sounds cool...

Comment: please how do I do this?